# How to create a new Woocommerce product tab?

Tags: php, wordpress, tabs, woocommerce

I need to create a new product tab called Category and Tags

Could you tell me how to do it without using plugins?

preview:

[image]

Comment: was my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to your function.php file, it will create another tab and now you can do what ever, in that callback function.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_cat_product_tab' );
function woo_cat_product_tab( $tabs ) {

    // Adds the new tab

    $tabs['tag_cat_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'Tag and Category', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'woo_cat_product_tab_content'
    );

    return $tabs;

}
function woo_cat_product_tab_content() {

    // The new tab content
    global $product;
    $id = $product->id;
    //Your code

}
```

for more details check [WooCommerce docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/#section-5).